# Check if UWB is turned on on devices that support it

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwb

I am currently facing a problem where my users update their phones and UWB turns on and it interferes with my ble scanning app. I want to write a function that tells them to turn it off and navigate them to the settings page where it is located. I cannot find any docs about this UWB library using java. My app is written in java and I have only found stuff related to kotlin.

I tried the following:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    if (packageManager != null){
        if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.uwb")){

        }
    }
```

but I don't know how to go further than this.

Comment: The Android documentation provides information in both languages: [Ultra-wideband](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/uwb?hl=en)
[Ultra-wideband (UWB) communication](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/uwb)